# get .cs files from an .appxbundle

Tags: c#, visual-studio, win-universal-app

I am having  problem with my universal project,in fact I have deployed my project on my first PC then when I open it with my second PC I didn't find many project files,so have you please any idea how can I get .cs files from an .appxbundle
thanks for help

UPdate:

I have debug my project and create a Release version,is there any valid Decompiler I can use to recover my C#/xaml code?? 
I have used "ILSpy" tool,but I didn't get any xaml code :(

Answer (score 1):

`.appxbundle` files do not contain the original source code. They contain compiled code only. You may be able to decompile some of the code using a decompiler (the bundles I believe are Zip files) but your original source is not in there.

Comment: so how can I recover the missing files Sir?

Comment: Like I said, you'd have to use a decompiler - but this won't get you your original source, just a vague approximation of it. You need to take better backups if you don't have any other copies of your code!